# How can I recover an answer to my question, which was deleted by a moderator?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71429737/4021436) regarding [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) and `.libPaths()` resolving [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).  There was an answer that appears to have been correct (from my memory), that I should accept.  However, it was deleted by a moderator, and I don't know how to 'restore' it.

What is the process for restoring previously deleted answers if you don't have sufficient reputation and can't even see the deleted answer?

I'm not looking for a Stack Overflow-specific answer to this question; I'd like an answer that can apply across the network.

Note: This question isn't a duplicate of ["When is it OK to vote to undelete posts that were deleted by their owners?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106619/339252), because this user didn't delete their answer.

Comment: The process would be to bring it up on the site's meta i.e. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ However the deleted answer looks quite a bit like a question rather than an answer.

Comment: *Can you rsync the folder with your packages over and then specify their new location with `.libPaths()`?*

Comment: that's the answer

Comment: I vaguely recall you can see the deleted answers for your own questions - if so, you could probably just flag it. That said, the answer probably needs editing from being a speculative question like thing, into a somewhat more confident answer.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't think so, more likely you remember that author of answer can still see it (with direct link) even when the parent question is deleted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it OK to vote to undelete posts that were deleted by their owners?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106619/282094) (for the question asker, on someone else's answer), and for the answer's author the duplicate is: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123806/282094

Comment: No, b/c I believe this answer was deleted by an admin.

Comment: irritable_phd_syndrome, You can not modify a question that already has an answer, so your [comment adding additional details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377129/how-to-recover-correct-answer-which-was-deleted-from-my-question#comment1257214_377129) requires a **new** question; [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145568/282094) does answer your question they way you originally asked it. Both the answer to this question ***and*** the modification in your comment are [answered in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/282094) - this question is a dupe regardless.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate b/c the author of the answer didn't delete the question.  So it isn't the same question as "When is it OK to vote to undelete posts that were deleted by their owners?".  The issue here is that a correct answer (even if it was framed more as a suggestion) was deleted and the user deserves the credit for the answer.  I feel like this answer was preferentially deleted due to the users low rep.  It is important to encourage new users and deleting answers that end up being correct isn't the right thing to do.

Comment: How is this question applicable to only one site?  The answer to provided by @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar, looks very much like an answer applicable to multiple sites.  Likewise with the edits to this question have now made it generic across sites

Comment: I totally agree, no idea what users have against this question. Already voted to reopen. The close reason can't be more wrong, since answers are deleted on **all** Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: FI, it *was* deleted by diamond-carrying moderator (♦). On 2022-03-11.

Comment: That Stack Overflow question is an example of why people shouldn't submit answers as rhetorical questions. "Try this" answers are not much better, but at least it is clear it is an attempt to answer (not, e.g., an attempt to circumvent to [the 50 reputation points limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)) - which is also a valid interpretation in this case, I think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question, here are some of the things you can do:

- Flag your own question, choosing "Other" and explaining you would like to have the answer undeleted. Mods might agree, or not. Up to them.
- Post a new question on the per-site meta, asking the same, or asking for screenshot of the answer at least so you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

If an answer was deleted by a moderator, it likely was not deleted by mistake. You should assume there is a reason why the answer was deleted, which makes it unlikely that the answer will ever be undeleted, unless it is edited to address the problem(s) which led to its deletion. Unless you are the original author of that answer, you cannot edit it while it is deleted, so mod-deleted answers are effectively gone forever.

As [Shadow Wizard says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377131), it is *possible* to raise a custom moderator flag on the associated question, explain the situation, and ask for the answer to be undeleted. This is a valid use of moderator flags. Moderators are exception-handlers, and you should call them in to do things which only moderators can do. Since only moderators can undelete a mod-deleted answer, moderator intervention is well and truly needed. But, as I said, absent any edits to the answer, unless it was truly deleted *as a mistake* (which is exceedingly rare, even on a site with as many mod-deleted answers as Stack Overflow), this is not likely to get it undeleted.

A better solution is to simply post a new answer that offers the same solution as the missing answer, but does a better job of presenting it. Specifically, a new answer that complies with [our minimum standards for an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

---

In this specific case, the deleted answer was:

> Can you rsync the folder with your packages over and then specify their new location with `.libPaths()`?

As is common in such cases, this answer was deleted by a moderator after it was flagged by (a) community member(s) as "not an answer".

This may have helped you toward a solution, but it really isn't an answer to the question as presented. You asked how "to prevent `.libPaths()` from resolving the symbolic link"; this doesn't doesn't achieve that directly, even though it may give you a hint on the path to take.

Ideally, such "hints" should be posted as comments. Then, you can review the hint, assess its applicability, hopefully use it to solve your problem, and then post a proper answer.

You can do the same thing, even if it was incorrectly posted as an answer and then deleted. A good answer would need to explain *why* that solves the problem, and also show *how* to use `.libPaths()`, rather than just allude to its existence.

Comment: Seeing this particular answer, and not knowing the reputation level of the answerer, a mod could have also opted to convert this to a comment, instead of a plain deletion. But let bygone's be bygones.